# Please login to this app again to reconnect with Facebook - error code 190

Tags: parse-platform

We are using:

Parse  - 1.8.3
FBSDK.*  - 4.6.0
ParseUI  - 1.1.6
ParseFacebookUtilsV4 - 1.8.3
IOS Target  - 9.0

Here is our issue. A user is logged into the app fine. They go into Facebook.com->Account->Settings and deauthorize the app (remove it entirely).

When the user launches our app again, they are greeted with a dialog from the FBSDK that says "Please login to this app again to reconnect with Facebook" (options are OK and Cancel).

I have googled/SO this and seen others with this issue, but in their case it is slightly different (and perhaps functional). This is because, when you click "OK" in that dialog, it does nothing. It appears that clicking ok is supposed to go do a login flow (which would be stellar), but again - it just does nothing.

I have tapped into the Notifications broadcast by the FBSDK and can see that I get a notification for:

com.facebook.sdk.FBSDKAccessTokenData.FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification

as a result of a error code 190 and sub_code 458.

My question is two part:
1) How do I get my "ok" button in the FBSDK Dialog that is automatically presented to actually DO something with the ok button?
2) How do I manually (assuming that the button above isn't working for some reason) test for the accessToken state and reauthorize the user?

This seems like there has to be a simple solution and I have spent a few days on it and cannot get ahead of this.

Thanks for any help or guidance!

Comment: I see now that the issue of click ok and it not working is because there is no access token, and thusly no permissions. So in the FBSDK when (_FBSDKLoginRecoveryAttempter attemptRecoveryFromError:) is called, the login part never executes. This seems like a bug? Is there a way to override this behavior and provide my own login recovery attempter?

Comment: Ok, I updated Parse and FBSDK to the most recent cocoa pods to see if that makes a difference and it does not.  This is easy to recreate. Simple remove the apps privileges from the Facebook Account Settings App tab and start the iOS app. With the latest SDK it will now try and login when "OK" is clicked from the error dialog, but the login does not appear to set a valid token and then the app is stuck in a state where the error dialog show at every app launch or when the app comes to the foreground.

Comment: If I am not wrong it is something like using oauth2 refreshToken for authentication .Please spend some more time and make it more clear, may be I had faced it and able to help you.

Comment: There are a few questions in there, but let's get to the root question (and probably the most important one).  When presented with the Facebook  error code 190 and sub_code 458, how do I successfully test the accessToken to determine it is in this state and subsequently, how do I reauthorize the user?    I have tried various FB/Oauth re-auth flows to no success thus far. A device restart or clean app install is the only fix at the moment.

Comment: We started having this issue with a small percentage of our uses also this past week.   restarting device, reinstalling app is not working.   It's happening to users that signed up via Facebook and users that manually created a user account via standard parse iOS sdk register user calls, and then those manually created uses later shared via Facebook.   We did just update Facebook and parse SDK's, and change to FB recommended login using webview instead of native FB we've been using past 2 years.

Comment: @Augie - I hear you loud and clear. We still haven't found a consistent way to address this (programmatically) for when it does happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem (it has nothing to do with Parse though). Here are my answers to the two questions you asked:

1. It seems the FBSDK dialog's OK button doesn't work for this reason:

   ```
   Attempt to present <FBSDKContainerViewController: 0x126b222a0> on
   <FBSDKContainerViewController: 0x126a26d10> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
   ```

   At least I see the above warning in the Xcode console when I try to log in to Facebook in my app (on a device connected to a Macbook) and my attempt fails. I didn't find a way to work around this particular problem. But I found a way to avoid the FBSDK dialog. See the next item.
2. I test for the validity of the accessToken by requesting the information about the FB user. If the request fails with an error, it may mean that the accessToken is not valid. Here is a code sample:

   ```
   FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] 
       initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, first_name, last_name"}];

   // The next line is important. 
   // It prevents FB SDK from handling the error automatically 
   // and allows you to handle the error yourself. 
   // In this way you avoid(!) the FBSDK dialog that says 
   // "Please login to this app again to reconnect with Facebook".
   [request setGraphErrorRecoveryDisabled:YES];

   [request startWithCompletionHandler:
       ^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){ 

       if (error) {
         // An error occurred. Most likely the accessToken is not valid.
         // Start the FB log-in process to obtain a valid token.
       }else{
         // Everything's all right. Go on.
       }
   }];
   ```

Comment: This is very good. disabling error recovery is the trick, I think. We ended up checking the session token and doing some things to ensure the state there, and that worked. But this has a more direct and strong overlap with what we did to work around the situation.